# Regular expression match fails if only whitespace after the - character

Tags: java, regex, string

I am working on a regular expression where the pattern is:

```
1.0.0[ - optional description]/1.0.0.0[ - optional description].txt
```

The [ - optional description] part is of course, optional.  So some possible VALID values are

```
1.0.0/1.0.0.0.txt
1.0.0/1.0.0.0 - xyz.txt
1.0.0 - abc/1.0.0.0 - xyz.txt
1.0.0 - abc/1.0.0.0.txt
```

To be a little more robust in the pattern matching, I'd like to match zero or more spaces before and after the "-" character.  So all these would be valid too.

```
1.0.0 - abc/1.0.0.0 - xyz.txt
1.0.0-abc/1.0.0.0-xyz.txt
1.0.0    -abc/1.0.0.0-     xyz.txt
```

To do this matching, I have the following regular expression (Java code):

```
String part1 = "((\\d+.{1}\\d+.{1}\\d+)(\\s*-\\s*(.+))?)";
String part2 = "((\\d+.{1}\\d+.{1}\\d+.{1}\\d+)(\\s*-\\s*(.+))?\\.sql)";
pattern = Pattern.compile(part1+ "/" + part2);
```

So far this regular expression is working well.  But while unit testing I found a case I can't quite figure out yet. The use case is if the string contains the "-" character is surrounded by 1 or more spaces, but there is no description after the "-" character. This would look like:

```
1.0.0 - /1.0.0.0.txt
1.0.0- /1.0.0.0-xyz.txt
```

In these cases, I want the pattern match to FAIL.  But with my current regular expression the match succeeds. I think what I want is if there is a "-" character surrounded by any number of spaces like "  - " then there must also be at least 1 non-space character following it.  But I can't quite figure out the regex for this.

Thanks!

Comment: `*` mean 0 or more , try using `+` mean 1 or more

Comment: @Michael your regex is large. Please try ([\w\s-./]+). Does it work??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like,

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\s*-\s*\w+)?\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\s*-\s*\w+)?.txt$
```

Or you can combine the `\.\d+` repetitions as

```
^\d+(?:\.\d+){2}(?:\s*-\s*\w+)?\/\d+(?:\.\d+){3}(?:\s*-\s*\w+)?.txt$
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/SXZOWo/2)**

---

**Changes**

- `.{1}` When you want to repeat something once, no need for `{}`. Its implicit
- `(?:\s*-\s*\w+)` Matches zero or more space (`\s*`)  followed by `-`, another space and then `\w+` a description of length greater than 1

  - The `?` at the end of this patterns makes this optional.
  - This same pattern is repeated again at the end to match the second part.
- `^` Anchors the regex at the start of the string.
- `$` Anchors the regex at the end of the string. These two are necessary so that there is nothing other in the string.
- Don't group the patterns using `()` unless it is necessary to capture them. This can lead to wastage of memory. Use `(?:..)` If you want to group patterns but not capture them

Comment: Thanks.  This got me very close.  I had to modify yours just a little bit to get what I wanted.  The main modification was to change your \w+.  this limited the description to only word characters, but I want to open the description up to also have whitespace characters.  So your \w+ I changed to \\S{1}.* which is any any single non-whitespace character followed by whatever.  And I did want to capture a bunch of groups so I added in the capturing groups.  This is what I ended up with:

`^((\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:\s*-\s*(\S{1}.*))?)\/((\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+)(?:\s*-\s*(\S{1}.*))?.txt)$`

Comment: @MichaelRemijan Happy to hear it helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

In the group that matches the optional part, you need to replace `.+` with `\\S+` where `\S` means any non-whitespace character. This enforces the optional part to include non-whitespace character in order to match the pattern:

```
String part1
    = "((\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+)(\\s*-\\s*(\\S+))?)";

String part2
    = "((\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+.{1}\\d+)(\\s*-\\s*(\\S+))?\\.txt)";
```

Also note that `.{1}` (which is the same as just `.`) matches any character. From the examples, you want to match a dot, so it should be replaced with `\.`

Answer (score 0):

Something like

```
^\d+\.\d+\.\d+(?:\s*-\s*[^\/\s]+)?\/\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+?(?:\s*-\s*[^.\s]+)?\.\w+$
```

[Check it out here at regex101](https://regex101.com/r/JnUyc5/2).